# Undefined offset notice with array within foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, prepared-statement

i have a form.php with an array posting to update.php to update a mysql db.
The relevant parts of each are:

form.php

```
 if ($type == "1")      {echo ' 
    <input type="hidden" id="assettype" name="atype[]" value="'. $row['AType'] .'"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="assetid" name="aid[]" value="'. $row['AID'] .'"/>

    <input  type="text"  name="serialnum[]" value="'. $row['SerialNumber'] .'"/>
    <input type="text"  name="unitsize[]" value="'. $row['UnitSize'] .'"/>
    <input type="text"  name="prop1[]" value="'. $row['Prop1'] .'"/>    
    <input  type="text"  name="latitude[]" value="'. $row['Latitude'] .'"/>
    <input  type="text"  name="longitude[]" value="'. $row['Longitude'] .'"/>
                ';}  
if ($type == "2")       {echo ' 
    <input type="hidden" id="assettype" name="atype[]" value="'. $row['AType'] .'"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="assetid" name="aid[]" value="'. $row['AID'] .'"/>

    <input type="text"  name="serialnum[]" value="'. $row['SerialNumber'] .'"/>
    <input type="text"  name="unitsize[]" value="'. $row['UnitSize'] .'"/>
    <input type="text"  name="prop2[]"  value="'. $row['Prop2'] .'"/>
    <input type="text"  name="latitude[]" value="'. $row['Latitude'] .'"/>
    <input type="text"  name="longitude[]" value="'. $row['Longitude'] .'"/>
                ';}
```

Update.php

```
foreach ($_POST['aid'] as $key=>$assetid) {
$atype = $_POST['atype'][$key];
if ($atype == "1")      {   

    $stmt =  $mysqli->stmt_init();
    $query = "UPDATE asset SET 
             SerialNumber=?,UnitSize=?,Prop1=?,Latitude=?,Longitude=?  WHERE AID = ?";
    if($stmt->prepare($query)) {

    $stmt->bind_param('sdddds', $serialnum, $unitsize, $prop1, $lat, $long, $assetid);

        $assetid = $_POST['aid'][$key];
        $serialnum = $_POST['serialnum'][$key];
        $unitsize = $_POST['unitsize'][$key];
        $prop1 = $_POST['prop1'][$key];
        $lat = $_POST['latitude'][$key];
        $long = $_POST['longitude'][$key];
        $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    }
}
elseif ($atype == "2")      {   

    $stmt =  $mysqli->stmt_init();
    $query = "UPDATE asset SET 
             SerialNumber=?,Prop2=?, Latitude=?,Longitude=? WHERE AID = ?";
    if($stmt->prepare($query)) {

    $stmt->bind_param('ssdds', $serialnum, $prop2, $lat, $long, $assetid);

        $assetid = $_POST['aid'][$key];
        $serialnum = $_POST['serialnum'][$key];
        $prop2 = $_POST['prop2'][$key];
        $lat = $_POST['latitude'][$key];
        $long = $_POST['longitude'][$key];
        $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
     }
}}
```

This works great for all but one of the inputs in the array.
I keep getting the following:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 3

relating to the following line:

```
$prop2 = $_POST['prop2'][$key];
```

All the other DB fields are updating fine except for this one. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: check how many indexes are u getting in $_POST['aid'] and $_POST['atype'] ... it must be same.. else u receive offset error.

Comment: if i use print_r its giving me the same number of each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use same name for this array input field. ie prop[] , but you used prop1[] and prop2[].

```
if ($type == "1")      {echo ' 
    <input type="hidden" id="assettype" name="atype[]" value="'. $row['AType'] .'"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="assetid" name="aid[]" value="'. $row['AID'] .'"/>

    <input  type="text"  name="serialnum[]" value="'. $row['SerialNumber'] .'"/>
    <input type="text"  name="unitsize[]" value="'. $row['UnitSize'] .'"/>
    <input type="text"  name="prop[]" value="'. $row['Prop1'] .'"/>    
    <input  type="text"  name="latitude[]" value="'. $row['Latitude'] .'"/>
    <input  type="text"  name="longitude[]" value="'. $row['Longitude'] .'"/>
                ';}  
if ($type == "2")       {echo ' 
    <input type="hidden" id="assettype" name="atype[]" value="'. $row['AType'] .'"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="assetid" name="aid[]" value="'. $row['AID'] .'"/>

    <input type="text"  name="serialnum[]" value="'. $row['SerialNumber'] .'"/>
    <input type="text"  name="unitsize[]" value="'. $row['UnitSize'] .'"/>
    <input type="text"  name="prop[]"  value="'. $row['Prop2'] .'"/>
    <input type="text"  name="latitude[]" value="'. $row['Latitude'] .'"/>
    <input type="text"  name="longitude[]" value="'. $row['Longitude'] .'"/>
                ';}
```

And in action page update like this:

```
$prop2 = $_POST['prop'][$key];
```

I don't know what logic you used, If there is a logical error use,

```
$prop2 = !empty($_POST['prop2'][$key]) ? $_POST['prop2'][$key] : '';
```